# Foundation (3) Zurb Drop Down Menu Issue

Tags: javascript, html, zurb-foundation

I have setup a basic "demo" page and am having trouble to get the Foundation Drop Down Menu to Function. As you can see here, http://tinyurl.com/arhssm9, Nav Item 2 has a dropdown option. However, nothing happens. I believe I have implemented the nav correctly and included the correct js files. I would really appreciate for someone to tell me where I went wrong so I can keep on going with my project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `app.js`. Just add it.

You can test running in your console:

```
$.getScript('https://raw.github.com/zurb/foundation/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/foundation/app.js');
```

Hope it helps.

---

EDIT

If you don't want to download extra JS, you can simply add something like:

```
var $doc = $(document);
$doc.ready(function(){
  $doc.foundationTopBar();
});
```

Comment: Hi Caarlos0 , thanks for the tip. I added the js file but it's still not working.

Comment: sorry, in the first version I paste the wrong file name. already fixed.

Comment: Yes, it's working great. This seems to be working: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://beta.domain.com/assets/javascripts/app.js">var $doc = $(document);
$doc.ready(function(){
  $doc.foundationTopBar();
});</script>